# Select records that have duration of StartDate and EndDate that not covered by Duration of given StartDate and EndDate

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have used LINQ to select records from a database table (Budgets) that have a structure like this:

- **ID**   *Integer* *Auto Incresement*
- **BudgetName**   *VarChar*
- **StartDate**    *DateTime*
- **EndDate**  *DateTime*

A Sample record:

```
ID      BudgetName          StartDate                       EndDate
1       budget              2016-03-14 04:33:09.737         2016-04-13 04:33:09.737
```

My VB Code that illustrate my idea of "Select records that have duration of StartDate and EndDate that not covered by Duration of given StartDate and EndDate":

```
Dim startDate = DateTime.Today
Dim endDate = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(1).AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1)
Dim budgets = (From item In dc.Budgets _
                Where Duration Of item.StartDate And item.StartDate Is Not Covered By Duration Of startDate And endDate _
                Select item)

'Note: Budgets is a System.Data.Linq.Table
```

I also have one more picture to illustrate my idea:

[image: Select records that have duration of StartDate and EndDate that not covered by Duration of given StartDate and EndDate]

**My issue is:** I don't know how to format a LINQ to achieve the result. So please help me to reformat my LINQ in the example above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your data is consistent i.e `EndDate` always greater or equals to `StartDate`, you can try this way :

```
Dim budgets = (From item In dc.Budgets _
                Where item.StartDate > endDate Or item.EndDate < startDate
                Select item)
```

The above query should select items which starts after the given `endDate` or ends before the given `startDate`, in other words, items which duration doesn't overlap the given duration.